# How can I establish communication between same-origin tabs?

Tags: javascript

The same-origin policy dictates that scripts on different pages are only allowed to access each other if and only if the pages which executed them are at locations with the same protocol, port number, and host.

Given two *independently opened* pages in the same origin, is it possible for those two pages to share scripts?

Comment: only if you opened the second one from the first one

Comment: @Ibu: Do you have references to back your claim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localStorage` is common to all open instances of an origin, and the `storage` event is fired in all of those instances when just one of them changes the `localStorage`. In this way, it is possible to identify and send messages to other instances of your site.

Comment: Ok, but `localStorage` isn't full sharing. One page cannot necessary call the other page's `console.log` with `localStorage` alone.

Comment: @levi: I want a generic way of doing it, even for websites I don't own.

Comment: you can with workers, make global one and send through message what you want to be executed in other page. You need to implements something like pub sub where message string is actualy a script which need to evaluated.

Comment: btw, there is no possibility to make this supported in old browsers

Comment: @MilanJaric: Could you please provide an example?